# Do image tags in sitemaps count towards the sitemap size limit?

Tags: url, sitemap, images

I am working on adding the `image:url` tags inside the `loc` tag in our sitemaps. The documentation from Google says I can include up to 1000, `image:url` inside a `loc` tag.

There is no mention if this 1000 per `loc` is counted towards the 50,000 URL per sitemap file limit. Does anyone have any reference to any official documentation regarding this? my research did not yield any official response.

Comment: Did you run your test?  If so, can you post the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that there is also a 50MB limit to the uncompressed sitemap size.   If each of your 50,000 pages had 1,000 images and each image entry in your sitemap were 50 bytes, your entire sitemap would end up being about 2GB.  Clearly that is too large. Even including about 20 images per page would put you right about at the 50MB limit.

I can't find any documentation that specifically addresses this question, but it seems prudent to be on the safe side and limit your sitemaps to 50,000 URLs of any type, pages or images.

Comment: i decided to test this scenario, i will create 3 xml files

1. file with 50K+ urls
2. file over 50MB size
3. file with standard url and image:url which will sum up to over 50K 

if number 3 results in similar errors as to files on 1 and 2 then we can conclude the limit is inclusive. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer @DevZer0